# Create a StackLayout inside a Frame in Xamarin Forms using C# as background code

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, code-behind, children

I use an `<Frame>` in my `xaml` page like this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Frame>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button></Button>
            <Label></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

But I want to do the same thing on the C# side.

I define the `StackLayout`, `Label` and `Button`.

Now I can add the `Button` to the `StackLayout` using `Children`, but I cannot add the `StackLayout` to the `Frame` because it doesn't have a `Children` property.

Is it possible to add a `StackLayout` inside a `Frame` using C# as background code ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A frame has a unique property: Content. Follow this snippet to create your UI in code behind:

```cs
var stackLayout = new StackLayout();
//add content...
stackLayout.Children.Add(new Label);
var frame = new Frame;
frame.Content = stackLayout
```

Moreover, if you want to have multiple children in your Frame, wrap it in an unique Container (Grid, RelativeLayout, AbsoluteLayout, ...)

See https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Frame/